# What is the use of the google analytics answer property?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I was taking a break and playing with objects in the chrome console, then I have found `ga.answer` that returns `42`, what is the use of that?

Comment: There's a pretty good description of it [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7578381) but basically, it's used to detect if Google Analytics has already been added to the page.

Comment: Probably just an easter egg. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=42

Comment: That's the answer, but what's the question? :-P

Comment: @George but `if(window.ga){ ... }` don't do this?

Comment: But what if I create a super cool library called "George is Awesome" that creates a global object called ga. If you read the comment on that link written by "timothya" it explains this.

Comment: @George what about `if(window[GoogleAnalyticsObject]){ ... }` ?

Comment: @George I readed the link, yes that's acceptable :)

Comment: @George if you use that link in your first comment as answer I will accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty good description of it [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7578381) but basically, it's used to detect if Google Analytics has already been added to the page

As a quote from that link

> It's not just a joke; it's actually used to make it less likely that another JavaScript on the page hasn't created a global variable called `ga` which may otherwise prevent the Analytics code from running.

Comment: But it's a joke too : )